# Nested streams to a Map Java 11

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

Let's say you have an interface, a couple of implementation classes and an Enum like this:
Interface:

```
public interface Employee {
    // No two employees will have same favorite hobbies
    List<Hobby> favoriteHobbies; 
}
```

Implementations:

```
public class Employee1 implements Employee {
    @Override
    public List<Hobby> favoriteHobbies {
        return List.of(Hobbies.swimming, Hobbies.dancing);
    }
}

public class Employee2 implements Employee {
    @Override
    public List<Hobby> favoriteHobbies {
        return List.of(Hobbies.running);
    }
}
```

Enum:

```
public enum Hobby {
    swimming,
    running,
    dancing
}
```

I have
`List<Employee> employees = List.of(Employee1, Employee2);`

And using Streams, I want to Stream through `employees` list and again Stream through each Employee object's `favoriteHobbies()` and create a `Map<Hobby, Employee>` like below:

```
"swimming" -> "Employee1"
"dancing" -> "Employee1"
"running" -> "Employee2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `Map.Entry` in a `Stream` and then collect it using its keys and values

Since [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16) this is possible using `Stream#mapMulti`

```java
Map<Hobby, Employee> map = employees.stream()
        .mapMulti((Employee employee, Consumer<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Hobby, Employee>> consumer) -> {
            employee.favoriteHobbies().forEach(hobby -> {
                consumer.accept(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(hobby, employee));
            });
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue,
                (entryOne, entryTwo) -> entryOne // or whatever, maybe even throw new XXXException()
        ));
```

Before [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16) this is possible with a `Stream#flatMap` and `Collectors#toMap`

```java
Map<Hobby, Employee> map = employees.stream()
        .flatMap(employee -> employee.favoriteHobbies()
                .stream()
                .map(hobby -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(hobby, employee)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue,
                (entryOne, entryTwo) -> entryOne // or whatever, maybe even throw new XXXException()
        ));
```

Which produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Good to know how Java-16 simplified it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9 it is possible to use [`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)), also a `LinkedHashMap` should be constructed to maintain insertion order of the map entries:

```java
Map<Hobby, Employee> map = employees()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.favoriteHobbies().stream().map(h -> Map.entry(h, e)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        Map.Entry::getValue, 
        (a, b) -> a, 
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

However, if the input `employees` list contains multiple instances of different implementations, it would make more sense to build a map `Map<Hobby, List<Employee>>` using `Stream::flatMap`, `Collectors::groupingBy`, `Collectors::mapping`, `Collectors::toList`:

```java
List<Employee> employeeList = List.of(
    new Employee1("John"), new Employee1("Jack"), new Employee2("Jeff"),
    new Employee1("Jake"), new Employee2("Jean")
);
Map<Hobby, List<Employee>> mapList = employees()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.favoriteHobbies().stream().map(h -> Map.entry(h, e)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        LinkedHashMap::new, 
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())         
    ));
```